# How to save json to a file using fetch() api?

Tags: fetch-api

index.html file placed in a folder and same folder has save.json file. Im running sublime text with server extension. **Error:** save.json 404 not found.

It can read from the same file but 404 when trying to write !

Pics below:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd8XU.jpg)

[Folder of index and save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1uE3.jpg)

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2C5o.jpg)

script below:

var OBJ = {

title: document.getElementById("title").innerHTML, 
body: document.getElementById("body").innerHTML, 
userId:  document.getElementById("userid").innerHTML,

};

fetch('/save.json', { 
method: 'POST', 
body: JSON.stringify(OBJ), 
headers: { 
'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
},
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => console.log(json));

Comment: Please post text as text, and not as images of text.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the code and the other contents of the images as text. You can use this guide to learn about formatting: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting